# How to select mails from a sender in mail app using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I want to select all the mails sent from a known Sender on a particular date in the default mail app on the mac using AppleScript. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try making a smart folder in mail.app meeting all your rules
Rules are easy to edit following your needs.

Tell us more if you really need AppleScript...